# Unity3D - Rotate image in XY axis when mouse over

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, image-rotation

I want to find out how to rotating image when it is hovered like this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=14_fxL8snv71yTd3F80Z6CsPeLKUQoco0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJu9S.jpg

I tried a lot of different options, but it works wrong.

```
Coroutine lastRoutine = null;

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData data)
    {
        lastRoutine = StartCoroutine(Test());
    }

        IEnumerator Test()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos.z = 0f;

            Vector3 objectPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
            mousePos.x = objectPos.x - mousePos.x;
            mousePos.y = objectPos.y - mousePos.y;

            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(angle, angle, 0));

        yield return null;
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData data)
    {
        StopCoroutine(lastRoutine);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I would approach what you are trying to do:

```
public class MouseEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float zOffset = -2f;
    public Vector2 tolerance = Vector2.one;
    Quaternion originalRotation;

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        // Storing the original rotation so we can reset to it when we aren't hovering anymore
        originalRotation= transform.rotation;
    }

    private void OnMouseOver()
    {
        Vector3 localOffset = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;

        // Multiplying by a adjustable tolerance, this is just a matter of preference if you want more rotation on the xAxis/yAxis or not.
        localOffset.x *= tolerance.x;
        localOffset.y *= tolerance.y;
        Vector3 worldOffset = transform.position + localOffset;

        // Setting a zOffset it will be really weird to adjust the rotation to look at something on the same Z as it.
        worldOffset.z = transform.position.z + zOffset;

        // Transform.LookAt for simplicity sake.
        transform.LookAt(worldOffset);
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        // This can cause a bit of a twitching effect if you are right on the edge of the collider.
        transform.rotation = originalRotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost what I need. But there are some problems: the turn from the top is wrong, and a small glitch due to originalRotation = transform.rotation and transform.rotation = originalRotation.
Look: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F23-KUxIKR0HxiCTm2K91m6GtvvbJPtL
How can i fix this?

Comment: @AlexPunto I mention the glitch on the OnMouseExit in a comment, there are a few ways you can adjust this, you can put all of this code in update, and store the original bounds of the object, if the mouse is within those bounds you do what is OnMouseOver,  you will still have a slight glitch, I would suggest using a coroutine and quaternion.slerp, to "Quickly" move the object back to its original position.